# How to assign iterated value to multiple global variables in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm querying a table with some specific column and want to store each value in different global variables.

When I'm trying to query only one row I'm able to store value in my global variable, but when I increase my LIMIT more than one my code doesn't work.

```
query = Select event, date, city, country from Table LIMIT 1;

event = ""
date = ""
city = ""
country = ""  

for row in cur.execute(query):
global event
global date
global city
global country

event, date, city, country = [row[i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 3)]
```

I want to store new value in global variable on every iteration. The result should look like this: -

```
Output: (On 1st Iteration)
event ="ABC"
date ="12 June"
city ="Delhi"
country ="India"

Output: (On 2nd Iteration)
event ="XYZ"
date ="2 May"
city ="New York"
country ="USA"

Output: (On 3rd Iteration)
event ="DDD"
date ="15 Sep"
city ="Tokyo"
country ="Japan"
```

Comment: it seems that your code is already doing this (except for the broken indentation)

Comment: Hi, Jean Thank you responding. The problem is that my code is not doing that...because when I'm trying to print the value its printing only first iterated value. Could you please me on this ... Thank you

Comment: the indentation of the code of your question is wrong. after the for statement code should be indented. fix that first